# Mobile Chrome home-screen webapp won't open index.php

Tags: php, android, html, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I've got a single webapp in a html/php file called index.php along with JS and CSS files. When you type in my domain, it will load the index.php file just like it normally would, but I would like for users to add this to their home-screen to use like an app.

So on my Android phone, running Lollipop, when I added it to my home-screen and I click on it, it will say it didn't find index.*html*, not index.php like it should be looking for.

My web server is a Rackspace VPS running apache2. I tried looking in the conf file for apache, but didn't see anything obvious as to how to make it go to index.php.

So my temporary solution for this was to make an index.html that redirects to index.php on the same level. I've encountered a few bugs that were not there before I changed it to a .php file instead of .html on the home-screen webapp side.

The only thing I'm using the php for is cookies management and detecting first-time users, so I really could drop the php and go with JS instead, but I like PHP a whole lot more so I would like to stick with that.

Thanks for any help in advance!

[Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/R51vTYh) of what opening the home-screen bookmark gets on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that done by creating a .htaccess file, in the same directory as index.php

Just create a file called .htaccess (make sure you have hidden files enabled on your machine) and add the following line and save:

DirectoryIndex index.php

This basically redirects domain.com/ to domain.com/index.php (without changing the way the url looks in the address bar)

Comment: Sure thing! let me know if you have any other qs!